# Change the default encoding in the Windows search dialog

Tags: windows-10, search, encoding, bom

In Windows 10, I have a directory of `sql` files.
The `file` command (from mingw i believe) outputs such:

```
Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

Because of the encoding, i don't see any results when searching by text, from the `Ctrl` + `F` dialog:

`No items matching your search`

I'm open to any and all approaches, be it command line, or some third party application on Windows.

Comment: one workaround is to use the `Find files` box in [Double Commander](https://github.com/doublecmd/doublecmd), however i had to specify the encoding to be `UCS-2LE` for it to work. I am hoping a way native to Windows for this. thanks.